# Can't write a function for building Huffman tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, huffman-code

I have got a `struct element`, which include information about element of tree.

```
struct element
{
    char ch;   //Letter
    int left;  //Number in array
    int right; //Number in arry
    int count; //Count letter in word
};
```

Also, I've got a function `MakeAlphabet`, which makes an alphabet for `std::string`:

```
std::vector<element> MakeAlphabet(std::string str)  //РАБОТАЕТ!
{
    std::vector<element> alphabet;
    ranges::sort(str);

    for(auto ch : str | ranges::views::unique)
    {
        alphabet.push_back(element{ch, -1, -1, static_cast<int>(ranges::count(str, ch))});
    }
    return alphabet;
};
```

Finally, I've got a function `MakeBinaryTree`:

```
std::vector<element> MakeBinaryTree(std::string str)
{
    std::vector<element> result;
    std::vector<element> alphabet = MakeAlphabet(str);
    std::sort(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());
    result = alphabet;
   
    int size = alphabet.size();
    result = alphabet;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i+=2)  //I think problem is here!
    {   
        alphabet.push_back(element{-1, i, i+1, (alphabet[i].count + alphabet[i+1].count)});
        alphabet.erase(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.begin() + 1);
        result.push_back(*(alphabet.end()-1));
    }
    return result;
};
```

When checking the root of the resulting tree (it must match the number of letters in the word), the result is almost always incorrect.

UPD:
I have overload operator for `std::sort(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());`.

```
bool operator<(const element &first, const element &second)
{
    return (first.count < second.count);
}

bool operator==(const element &first, const element &second)
{
    return (first.count == second.count);
}
```

Comment: `std::sort(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end())` shouldn't compile - `element` doesn't provide `operator<`. At least, there's none in the code shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have overload of `operator<`. Already , update a question.

Comment: Your loop never looks at half the original elements. The first iteration examines `alphabet[0]` and `alphabet[1]`. Then it erases the first element; all other elements shift leftward. On the next iteration, it examines what are now `alphabet[2]` and `alphabet[3]`, but were previously `alphabet[3]` and `alphabet[4]`. The element that originally was at `alphabet[2]` and is now at `alphabet[1]` is never looked at.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So, the code is correct, I just have to change the numbers? Change `i` to 0 and 1, right?

Comment: Well, I don't know enough about the problem to tell you how to fix it; I don't really understand what you are doing. But whatever it is, skipping half the elements seems wrong.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I want to write a function that will build the Huffman tree for some word. The tree is represented as an array. That's all.

Comment: To my eternal shame, I don't know what a "Huffman tree" is, and so can't help you build one. I just know enough to point out an obvious mistake. Fixing it is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The Huffman tree is the data structure, like binary tree, used to compress data. With a Huffman tree, we can create a variable length encoding for some alphabet that will not break the prefix rule.

Comment: If you believe this brief description is sufficient to implement one, then go ahead and implement one. You clearly already know more about this data structure than I do.

Comment: @Bogdasar Can you provide the complete code? I've implemented one earlier and may be able to help you

Comment: @asds_asds https://pastebin.com/C5d82kKq

Comment: I think I was wrong to choose the book about algorithms (by Panos Louridas). It implements the Huffman Code in chapter one. It's stupid. Now I've moved on to "Grokking algorithms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a priority_queue instead of a vector.

Go through Huffman Encoding once if you want.

I have re-implemented the `MakeBinaryTree` function using a `priority_queue`.

Everything else remains the same.

Sample Case:-

```
character   Frequency
    a            5
    b           9
    c           12
    d           13
    e           16
    f           45
```

Expected Result:-

[image: Resultant Tree]

Final Output in `std::vector<element>`:

```
Index       Character   Frequency
   0          .      100
   1          f       45
   2          .       55
   3          .       25
   4          .       30
   5          c       12
   6          d       13
   7          .       14
   8          e       16
   9          a        5
  10          b        9
```

`.` indicates an internal node.

Working Code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <string_view>
#include <deque>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/count.hpp>
#include <range/v3/action/sort.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/unique.hpp>
#include <exception>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct element //Элемент бинарного дерева.
{
    char ch;
    struct element* left;
    struct element* right;
    int count;
};

bool operator<(const element &first, const element &second)
{
    return (first.count > second.count); // Reversed to form min heap instead of default max heap
}

bool operator==(const element &first, const element &second)
{
    return (first.count == second.count);
}

std::vector<element> MakeAlphabet(std::string str)  //РАБОТАЕТ!
{
    std::vector<element> alphabet;
    ranges::sort(str);

    for(auto ch : str | ranges::views::unique)
    {
        alphabet.push_back(element{ch, NULL, NULL, static_cast<int>(ranges::count(str, ch))});
    }
    return alphabet;
};


std::vector<element> MakeBinaryTree(std::string str)    //НЕ работает.
{
    std::vector<element> result;
    std::vector<element> alphabet = MakeAlphabet(str);
    std::priority_queue<element> min_heap;
    //Initialize Min Heap
    for(auto x:alphabet)
        min_heap.push(x);

    // Form Huffman Encoding Tree
    while(min_heap.size()>1){
        element *lc = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));*lc=min_heap.top();min_heap.pop();
        element *rc = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));*rc=min_heap.top();min_heap.pop();
        min_heap.push(element{'.',lc,rc,lc->count + rc->count});
    }
    std::queue<element> prefix_traversal;
    prefix_traversal.push(min_heap.top());

    // Convert Tree to Vector using BFS
    while(prefix_traversal.size()>0){
        element top = prefix_traversal.front();
        prefix_traversal.pop();
        result.push_back(top);
        if(top.left != NULL)
            prefix_traversal.push(*top.left);
        if(top.right != NULL)
            prefix_traversal.push(*top.right);

    }
    return result;
};



int main(){
    std::string s;
    for(int i=0;i<13;i+=1)s+="d";
    for(int i=0;i<9;i+=1)s+="b";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i+=1)s+="a";
    for(int i=0;i<12;i+=1)s+="c";   
    for(int i=0;i<16;i+=1)s+="e";
    for(int i=0;i<45;i+=1)s+="f";
    std::vector<element> result = MakeBinaryTree(s);
    printf("Index   \tCharacter\tFrequency\n");
    for(int i=0;i<result.size(); i+=1){
        // std::cout<<"Index "<<i<<" "<<result[i].ch<<" "<<result[i].count<<std::endl;
        printf("%4d\t\t%3c\t\t%4d\n",i,result[i].ch,result[i].count);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array must be sorted, the two nodes with the smallest occurrences are taken to form a new node that is put back in the array. The array is sorted again and so on...
Thus it is only one array, i.e. alphabet

Use pointers to element (element*) instead of element only, because it is easy to switch them from the array to the tree.

Create a node class

```
class node{
};

class inner_node: public node
{
    node *left, *right;
    int count; //Count letter in word
};

class element: public node
{
public:
    char ch;   //Letter
    int count; //Count letter in word
};

std::vector<node*> MakeAlphabet(std::string str)  //РАБОТАЕТ!
{
    std::vector<node*> alphabet;
    ranges::sort(str);

    for(auto ch : str | ranges::views::unique)
    {
        element *e = new element();
        e->ch = ch;
        e->static_cast<int>(ranges::count(str, ch));
        alphabet.push_back(e);
    }
    return alphabet;
}

std::vector<node*> MakeBinaryTree(std::string str)
{
    std::vector<node*> alphabet = MakeAlphabet(str);

    // keep going until there is only the huffman tree root left in the vector
    while(alphabet.size() > 1)
    {   
        std::sort(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());

        // Takes last two elements and remove them
        inner_node *first  = (inner_node*) alphabet.back();
        alphabet.pop_back();
        inner_node *second = (inner_node*) alphabet.back();
        alphabet.pop_back();

        // Creates tree node and put in the vector
        inner_node *n = new node();
        n->left = first;
        n->right = second;
        n->count = first->count + second->count;
        alphabet.push_back(n);
    }
    return alphabet;
}
```